# Query many webpages to get all products of a webstore?

Tags: web-scraping, request

for personal interest I wanna create a list with all products a webstore has. In Germany there are two big companies called "Media Markt" and "Saturn". "Media Markt"'s system is easy, they use a 7 digit number as ID for their products. So I wanna get all those products but I think doing 10 million requests in 12 threads (bcs of my PC has 12 cores) in a short time will overwhelm the server or make the server ignoring my requests after a short time. What can I do to get this list with all products?
I am thankful for any ideas.

Comment: Your question is way too broad for this forum. What you are refering to here is often called scraping discovery and I have a blog post on this here: https://scrapecrow.com/web-scraping-discovery.html 

Brute forcing 10 million requests sounds like a bad idea. Take a look at other discovery approaches mentioned in the blog. Looks like both of your websites have some sort of sitemap, the blog covers how to scrape targets with sitemaps.

Comment: Thank you very much :D